Why Typescript types Object.groupBy as Partial
When I use Object.groupBy in typescript the return type looks something like this Partial<Record<string, T[]>>. But, shouldn't it be just Record<string, T[]>?
The reasoning is: if the groups were created by entries in the original array, why would an entry be missing in the output?
Here is an example:
const people = [
    {name: 'Santi', country: 'Mexico'},
    {name: 'Jacqueline', country: 'France'},
    {name: 'Pablo', country: 'Mexico'},
];
const byCountry = Object.groupBy(people, person => person.country)

// equivalent to
const byCountry: Partial<Record<string, Person[]>> = {
  Mexico: [
    { name: 'Santi', country: 'Mexico' },
    { name: 'Pablo', country: 'Mexico' }
  ],
  France: [
    { name: 'Jacqueline', country: 'France' }
  ],
}

The problem is that since byCountry is partial, I get errors when working with the result
Object.values(byCountry).map(people => people.length) // 'people' is possibly undefined

Whereas with this snippet it all just simply work:
const byCountry2: Record<string, Person[]> = {
  Mexico: [
    { name: 'Santi', country: 'Mexico' },
    { name: 'Pablo', country: 'Mexico' }
  ],
  France: [
    { name: 'Jacqueline', country: 'France' }
  ],
}

Object.values(byCountry2).map(people => people.length)


There are plenty of ways for a property to be undefined, as shown in this playground link. Does that sufficiently demonstrate what's going on? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

I'd argue the problem in your code is more with the type of Object.values, which should ignore optional properties.

In the TypeScript repository issue related to the typings, multiple comments point out that Record would be unsound when the array is empty, which would produce an object with no keys, and thus the typings were updated to use Partial<Record>. (1, 2)

And since Daniel is already comparing this to Object.fromEntries above, I think Ryan’s reasoning on the type correctness there would probably also apply:

It's not correct to use the input type to determine the output type, because knowing what might be in an array is not the same as knowing what's actually in it. This program is legal per the above definitions but unsound [...]
(3)


declare function 
    ObjectGroupBy<Item, K extends PropertyKey>(
      items: Iterable<Item>,
      keySelector: (item: Item, index: number) => K,
    ): Record<K, Item[]>;

let x = ObjectGroupBy([] as number[], x => x < NaN ? 'small' : 'large');
//  ^ Record<"small" | "large", number[]>
console.log(x.small) // undefined




https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47171#issuecomment-1848451195
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47171#issuecomment-1848451195
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47171#issuecomment-1858674657

